# NgIdleModule does not have 'emod' property error

Tags: angular, angular13

I know that this error often shows up because someone puts something in the `imports` section of `module.ts` that doesn't belong there like a component name, or something similar.

But I went from having a functioning project to having this error without even touching the `imports` or `module.ts` or any of that. I added a completely different package with `yarn`, called `moment`, I didn't even attempt to use it yet in any files, and suddenly my previously functioning project started complaining about the `NgIdleModule` not having `emod` property.

I removed `moment`, and still the error stays. It doesn't make any sense. The `@ng-idle/core` uses the `NgIdleModule.forRoot()` for the import which I am and always have been using. Now all of a sudden it thinks there is an error. Anyone knows why it suddenly isn't working?

Again, this all started when I added a new package to `package.json`, but even after removing the new thing from my project the error for `NgIdleModule` persists. I read that it might have something to do with **ivy compiler** as I'm using Angular 13, so I upgraded to `ng2-idle-core library`, fixed the issue for a bit, and now randomly it comes back again.

Comment: Now I'm getting this: This likely means that the library (@ng-idle/core) which declares NgIdleModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.